# exclude images in data scrape/output (php)

Tags: php, xpath

Very new to php but stumbled upon some nice coding below that gets all contents from a given url, with a specific tag as an identifier. One issue is though, I like the text it outputs, and the fact that it retains the original URL links, if the text is clicked, BUT it also prints out a few images. I'd like to get rid of the images. Is there something that can be included in this text that IGNORES images? Thanks so much, for any help. Last time I posted about this, I seemed to get a lot of grief for some reason.

If somehow I've offended anyone, I'm sorry. I'm just seeing if I can get any assistance. I'm not demanding, or even expecting anything from anyone. Just seeing what help I can get, if any. Wasn't sure why people were upset previously, hoping it doesn't occur again. I'm absolutely not looking to upset the stackoverflow community, who I'm very grateful for and has helped me tremendously with php and learning php.

What I have tried, is this, but it isn't affecting the images, because obviously I'm doing something wrong. I'm not sure precisely my error.

```
$content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "(image) ", $content);
```

original code:

```
<?php
// news
$doc = new DOMDocument;

// We don't want to bother with white spaces
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;


$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->recover = true;

$doc->loadHTMLFile('https:/_________/');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$query = "//ul[@class='hfwmm-list hfwmm-4uphp-list hfwmm-light-list']//a";

$entries = $xpath->query($query);
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
$oldHref = (string)$entry->getAttribute("href");
$entry->setAttribute("href", "http://__________.com".$oldHref);
$newdoc = new DOMDocument();
$cloned = $entry->cloneNode(TRUE);
$newdoc->appendChild($newdoc->importNode($cloned,TRUE));
 echo $newdoc->saveHTML();
}

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try query like below:

```
$query = "//ul[@class='hfwmm-list hfwmm-4uphp-list hfwmm-light-list']//a[not(img)]";
```

It will all the `<a>` tags excluding the one which has `<img>` tag.